# CISoftLightBlendMode not centered on Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, core-image

hey I'm having a problem with the CISoftLightBlendMode when I apply the filter to the image the overlay image is not centered over the other image it just stays in the bottom left corner  so only a very small portion of the image is covered by the overlay texture.

Heres my code:

```
UIImage* bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Texture.png"];
CIImage* beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[image_view.image CGImage]];
CIImage* bgImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:bg.CGImage];
context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISoftLightBlendMode" keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage,@"inputBackgroundImage",bgImage, nil];
CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
[Image_View setImage:newImg];
```

Comment: Are your input images the same size?

Comment: yes both of them are 320x320 pixels